# Has any player beat both of the Williams sisters in singles games within a week?

Tags: trivia, tennis, wta

Victoria Azaranka beat Serena Williams 2-1 on September 10th, 2020 at the US Open semis. She went on to beat Venus Williams 2-0 on September 16th, 2020 at the Italian Open.

The timing worked nicely for Azaranka to beat the Williams sisters within a week in 2 tournaments as she beat Serena in the second last match of the women's singles of US Open, and faced Venus on the first round of the next WTA tournament, the Italian Open. Otherwise this feat might have been easier done in just one tournament.

Given the dominant run the Williams sisters have had in the past 20+ years, I wonder had thy been beat in a week by the same player ever before in single's tournaments?

Comment: I'm not sure this meets my minimum bar of "relevant statistic".  Beat the sisters in one tournament, perhaps, but in one calendar week?

Comment: Well if it's happened in a tournament then it should be easier to get an answer. If no answers I'll try to scrape a source, if I find any

Answer (score 2):

#### 2001 Australian Open

**Martina Hingis** defeated Serena in QF 6-2 3-6 8-6 and Venus in SF 6-1 6-1
Martina lost the final though to Jennifer Capriati.

#### 2007 US Open

**Justine Henin** defeated Serena in QF 7-6 6-1 and Venus in SF 7-6 6-4
Justine won the final against Svetlana Kuznetsova

#### 2009 US Open

**Kim Clijsters** defeated Venus in 4R 6-0 0-6 6-4 and Serena in SF 6-4 7-5
Kim won the final against Caroline Wozniacki

#### 2010 Italian Open

**Jelena Janković** defeated both sisters in a 24-hour period, the only player to do so. Venus in the QF 6-0 6-1 and Serena in the SF 4-6 6-3 7-6 (5)
Jelena lost the final though to María José Martínez Sánchez

#### 2016 US Open

**Karolína Plíšková** defeated Venus in 4R 4-6 6-4 7-6 and Serena in SF 6-2 7-6
Karolína lost the final though to Angelique Kerber

Comment: Good answer, can you also provide links to source/match results?